# partial derivative variable substitution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$x=f(s,t) , y=g(s,t) , z=h(s,t)$ , how to compute $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$?

Is it unavoidable to first find some function $u$ and $v$ so that $s=u(x,y), t=v(x,y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For chain rule
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$$

we need $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$ from system
$$\begin{cases}
f'_s \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+f'_t \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}=1 \\
g'_s \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+g'_t \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}=0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Here both $s$ and $t$ are functions of $x$, so $\frac{dF}{dx}=F_x+F_s\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+F_t\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$. You cannot assume that $t$ is a constant.

Comment: That assumption is used in the proof of the theorem for implicit function. As you can see in the formula I give in the previous comment, for $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$ to be $-\frac{F_x}{F_s}$, $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$ has to be 0.

Comment: @John Ao.. You are right. Thanks. Fixed.